# ESP32 OTA read local files

Tags: html, esp32, ota

I have this code in html, which has a form to send files, but I would like to read these files directly from a path on the computer, how do I do that? I'm new to the language
Thanks

```cpp
const char* serverIndex = 
"<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js'></script>"
"<form method='POST' action='#' enctype='multipart/form-data' id='upload_form'>"
   "<input type='file' name='update'>"      
    "</form>"
 "<div id='prg'>Progresso: 0%</div>"
 "<script>"
  "$('form').submit(function(e){"
  "e.preventDefault();"
  "var form = $('#upload_form')[0];"
  "var data = new FormData(form);"
  " $.ajax({"
  "url: '/update',"
  "type: 'POST',"
  "data: data,"
  "contentType: false,"
  "processData:false,"
  "xhr: function() {"
  "var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();"
  "xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(evt) {"
  "if (evt.lengthComputable) {"
  "var per = evt.loaded / evt.total;"
  "$('#prg').html('Progresso: ' + Math.round(per*100) + '%');"
  "}"
  "}, false);"
  "return xhr;"
  "},"
  "success:function(d, s) {"
  "console.log('Sucesso!')"
 "},"
 "error: function (a, b, c) {"
 "}"
 "});"
 "});"
 "</script>";
```

Example:

I would like to read this file
`file:///C:/Users/Matheus/Desktop/test.bin`

Comment: Are you saying that the form works but you want to be able to have your web page read files from the computer without using the form or having any user interaction?

Comment: Exactly, is it possible to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read/write local files through a web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12023858/how-to-read-write-local-files-through-a-web-page)